# WebSphere SOAP web service intermittently getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out and the server going down

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere

I have SOAP webservices deployed on websphere application server and some times I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException and the server is not responding for all other requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check. If -nothing- works after you see this (admin console unresponsive, local admin port unresponsive, etc.) then the server might be very low on memory or cpu, so is unable to respond to anything.  If restarting the server clears it up for awhile, that also points to something about the server.  Or, there could be something wrong with the network and communication has failed with that last timeout.  If so, restarting the network might clear it up.  Finally there could be something wrong with the OS hosting the server, like almost out of native memory.  Also, look in the logs for warnings and errors.